# "ConcurrentlyModifiedException Message: Routine caused exception: History_UpdateCursorProgress." when rebuilding reporting database

Tags: xconnect, reporting

- I followed below document to set up multiple processing server (i created 3 processing server)
  https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/processing/index.html
- After that i tried to rebuild reporting database and got some exceptions in log files of processing servers as below

```
14416 20:44:14 WARN Cursor with id d1470ede-fbb5-4983-85b8-03fe5cca89d2 (TaskId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) has been concurrently modified. It means the task has been completed, canceled, failed, or expired concurrently. Please consider increasing ownership time for cursors.***

***Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Data.ConcurrentlyModifiedException Message: Routine caused exception: History_UpdateCursorProgress. Source: Sitecore.Analytics.Sql***

***Nested Exception***

***Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Message: The interaction cursor has been concurrently modified. Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider***

***14416 20:44:14 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/historyWorker Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Data.ConcurrentlyModifiedException Message: Routine caused exception: History_UpdateCursorProgress. Source: Sitecore.Analytics.Sql
```

what wrong with it ? Did i miss any setting for configuring multiple processing server ?

I'm working on Sitecore 9.0 Update 1

Thanks!

Comment: You need to contact Sitecore Support regarding this unique problem and then post answer here for others.

Answer (score 0):

If the processing of a single batch is bigger than OwnershipTimeout, or processing was stopped and started after OwnershipTimeout is passed, all agents start to receive the task even if one is already working on it. Each time agent asks for a task the task is returned even if a cursor split is already requested. but the current agent is working on the task and will split the cursor only after it processed the first batch. The first agent takes the task and starts the work. The others receive tasks, and can't use the cursor as it is not splittable and in progress

You will need to increase the ownershipTimeoutMs parameter in the `App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.xDB\Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.Aggregation.config` file to resolve the exception:

```
<param desc="ownershipTimeoutMs" type="Sitecore.Analytics.Core.ConfigurationHelper, Sitecore.Analytics.Core" factoryMethod="ToInt" arg0="180000" />
```